# TFS administrator task logging

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to track who (among the project administrators) has removed a user or added a user in a Team project.

So the scenario is like this:
i have a team project where there is 2 project admins, admin1 and admin2. Now i want to find out who among the admin1 and admin2 has added a new user userN to the contributor of the team project.

Comment: Read that

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2013/03/30/how-to-see-activity-and-job-history-in-tfs-2012/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS doesn't provide such a traciking log by default. But you can check web-based administration interface `http://your-server:8080/tfs/_oi/` for some things inside of TFS.

I just added a user, then I can see there is a ApiIdentity.AddIdentities command executed under my Identity.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there no way i can get the info even if i query the DB?